# Custom number of successful executions in the Execution Performance report in the Integration Services Catalog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssms

I want to ask if it is possible to change parameter "**number of successful executions**" inside the **Execution Performance** report in the **Integration Services Catalog**?

See picture:
[image]

Let say I would like to see 1000 instead of just 10 executions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a .rdl report integrated in SSMS.
Microsoft [described](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153687.aspx) that these reports are available among **Report Samples**, and provides a way how to add your custom report to SSMS.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the report samples are not currently available. :(